# Dynamic SQL syntax issue for password change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working on SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and I have been working on a password generator that will automatically change a SQL password of the supplied user name. I found the script in another location and modified it a bit. The problem I have is that when I run the script it errors out. Below is the code and after is the error.

```
set nocount on

declare @PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH    int
declare @PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH    int
declare @LOGIN          SYSNAME

select @PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 25
select @PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 25
select @LOGIN = 'Test_User'

declare @PASSWORD_DATA table (PASSWORD_CHAR VARCHAR(1) )
declare @NUM table ( DIGIT int not null primary key clustered)

insert into @NUM (DIGIT)
    select DIGIT =  0 union all select DIGIT =  1 union all
    select DIGIT =  2 union all select DIGIT =  3 union all
    select DIGIT =  4 union all select DIGIT =  5 union all
    select DIGIT =  6 union all select DIGIT =  7 union all
    select DIGIT =  8 union all select DIGIT =  9
    order by 1

insert into @PASSWORD_DATA (PASSWORD_CHAR)
select
    PASSWORD_CHAR = 
    substring(b.CHARACTERS,a.RAND_INT%b.MOD,1)
from
    (select
         aa.NUMBER,
         RAND_INT = abs(convert(int, convert(varbinary(100), newid())))
     from
         (select
              NUMBER = a.DIGIT+(b.DIGIT*10)
          from
              @NUM a    
          cross join 
              @NUM b) aa
) a
cross join
    (select
         MOD = len(bb.CHARACTERS)-1,
         bb.CHARACTERS
     from
         (select
              CHARACTERS = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ' +
                           'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz' +
                           'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ' +
                           'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz' +
                           'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ'+
                           'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz' +
                           'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ'+
                           'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz' +
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '23456789'+
                           '@#$^*+=<>?'+
                           '@#$^*+=<>?'+
                           '@#$^*+=<>?'+
                           '@#$^*+=<>?') bb
     ) b
order by
    newid()

--select * from @PASSWORD_DATA

declare @password varchar(100)

select @password = ''

select @password = @password+PASSWORD_CHAR
from @PASSWORD_DATA

select @password = 
    -- Random length from MIN to MAX characters
    substring(@password,1,
    @PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH +
    (abs(convert(int,convert(varbinary(100),newid()))))%(@PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH -@PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH+1)) 

print 
'

PASSWORD = '+@password+'


exec master.dbo.sp_password
    @old = NULL ,
    @new = '''+@password+''', 
    @loginame = '''+isnull(@LOGIN,'''')+'''

    '

    exec master.dbo.sp_password
    @old = NULL ,
    @new = '''+@password+''', 
    @loginame = '''+isnull(@LOGIN,'''')+'''
```

After the `exec master.dbo.sp_password` runs it gives me the following error.

> Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_password, Line 142
>   ''+isnull(@LOGIN,'')+'' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.

I'm looking to turn this into a stored procedure to automatically generate and change SQL passwords when asked. Any help would be appreciated. PS. I am the Sys Admin on the box.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
IF @LOGIN IS NOT NULL
exec master.dbo.sp_password
@old = NULL ,
@new = @password, 
@loginame = @LOGIN
```

Comment: That's exactly what it took.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be where you need some dynamic SQL:

```
set nocount on
declare @PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH    int
declare @PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH    int
declare @LOGIN          SYSNAME
select @PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 25
select @PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 25
select @LOGIN = 'Test_User'

declare @PASSWORD_DATA table (PASSWORD_CHAR VARCHAR(1) )
declare @NUM table ( DIGIT int not null primary key clustered)

----------------------------
DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(4000);
-----------------------------

insert into @NUM (DIGIT)
select DIGIT =  0 union all select DIGIT =  1 union all
select DIGIT =  2 union all select DIGIT =  3 union all
select DIGIT =  4 union all select DIGIT =  5 union all
select DIGIT =  6 union all select DIGIT =  7 union all
select DIGIT =  8 union all select DIGIT =  9
order by 1

insert into @PASSWORD_DATA (PASSWORD_CHAR)
select
    PASSWORD_CHAR = 
    substring(b.CHARACTERS,a.RAND_INT%b.MOD,1)
from
(
select
    aa.NUMBER,
    RAND_INT    = 
    abs(convert(int,convert(varbinary(100),newid())))
from
    (
    select
        NUMBER = a.DIGIT+(b.DIGIT*10)
    from
        @NUM a  cross join @NUM b
    ) aa
) a
cross join
(
select
    MOD = len(bb.CHARACTERS)-1,
    bb.CHARACTERS
from
    (
    select
        CHARACTERS =
        'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ'+
        'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz'+
        'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ'+
        'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz'+
        'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ'+
        'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz'+
        'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQURSUVWXYZ'+
        'abcdefghjkmnpqursuvwxyz'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '23456789'+
        '@#$^*+=<>?'+
        '@#$^*+=<>?'+
        '@#$^*+=<>?'+
        '@#$^*+=<>?'
    ) bb
) b
order by
    newid()

--select * from @PASSWORD_DATA

declare @password varchar(100)

select @password = ''

select @password = @password+PASSWORD_CHAR
from @PASSWORD_DATA

select @password = 
    -- Random length from MIN to MAX characters
    substring(@password,1,
    @PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH +
    (abs(convert(int,convert(varbinary(100),newid()))))%(@PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH -@PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH+1)) 

print 
'

PASSWORD = '+@password+'


exec master.dbo.sp_password
    @old = NULL ,
    @new = '''+@password+''', 
    @loginame = '''+isnull(@LOGIN,'''')+'''

    '
----------------------------------------------  
SELECT @TSQL = '
exec master.dbo.sp_password
    @old = NULL ,
    @new = '''+@password+''', 
    @loginame = '''+isnull(@LOGIN,'''')+''''

EXECUTE sp_executesql @TSQL
----------------------------------------------
```